# Symfony 2.5.9 - Url generated by asset_url isn't matching the actual file

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having a strange issue with a Symfony 2 deployment to production.

After running:
php app/console assets:install --env=prod
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod

A css file is generated in web/css, for example "53xyz.css".

However, the twig template is outputting the url "53xyz_part_1_style_1.css" which is causing a 404.

Same goes for other assets using the asset_url in a stylesheets or javascripts block.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache and then dumping the assets?

Comment: I have. Same thing is happening. It starting to look like assetic still thinks it's running in dev.

Comment: the problem happens in prod environment, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Just figured it out after more research.

In /web/app.php the line
`$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`

needs to be:
`$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);`

The second flag is a debug flag that when it's set to true will generate the debug file names. When it's false, it'll use the file name you expect.